# script auto looping after reaching a certain point in text based game

Tags: python

my text based game goes in a loop after going "right" and it won't stop unless you stop the process

heres the code in python:

```
def entrance():
  
    import os
    import sys 
      
    print ('hello please type your name in')
    name = input('')
    print ('hello' ,name,)
    print('''                   
                              .___.          
                /)               ,-^     ^-.
                //               /           \                                                                                                                                  |WMWMWMW| |>>>>>>>>>>>>> | />>\   />>\ |>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>:>
      `-------| |--------------| \__/   \__/ |-------------------'^^
              \\                \    /|\    /
                \)               \   \_/   /
                                  |       |
                                  |+H+H+H+|
                                  \       /
                                  ^-----^
  

     ''')
    print("Welcome to Run Run Run" ,name,)
    print("Your mission is to find the your way out of a abandonded hospital.")

    #this game is text based where you have to escape without disturbing "it" 
    directions = ["left" ,"right" ,"back"]
    print('You awaken in what looks like the reception of the hospital. You feel like something is watching you but you ignore it. there are cobwebs and everything is in ruins. there are two doors which one do you go through?')
    userinput = " "
    while userinput not in directions:
      print('options: left/right/back')
      userinput = input()
      #used if and elif to get more accurate answers
      if userinput == "right":
        TheHall()
      elif userinput == "left":
        death1()
      elif userinput == "back":
        NoReturn()
      else:
        print('type a valid option')   
      
def NoReturn():
  print('the door is locked you cant get out')
  entrance()
      
def TheHall():
  print('Continuing through the door, you have come upon a beam in the hallway. Beyond the beam, the floor appears to turn into blood. If you choose to continue down the blood path,')
  Continue()
      
def Continue():
  directions = ["forward" ,"back"]
  print('You have continued down the hall. It turns out blood isnt as big of a deal as the movies make it out to be. The trail leads you to a room. There is rickety wooden plank leading to the other side. At the foot of the plank there are 3 beautiful feathers. To your left there is, nothing.')
  userinput = " "
  while userinput not in directions:
    print('options: forward/back')
    if userinput == "forward":
      bridge()
    elif userinput == "back":
      entrance()
```

i have no idea what do to. i tried indenting it but it didn't work instead it presented me with an indentation error

Comment: You never ask for new input in Continue

Answer (score 0):

In the Continue funcion you don't take input, you can just change code to

```
def Continue():
  directions = ["forward" ,"back"]
  print('You have continued down the hall. It turns out blood isnt as big of a deal as the movies make it out to be. The trail leads you to a room. There is rickety wooden plank leading to the other side. At the foot of the plank there are 3 beautiful feathers. To your left there is, nothing.')
  userinput = " "
  while userinput not in directions:
    print('options: forward/back')
    userinput = input()
    if userinput == "forward":
      bridge()
    elif userinput == "back":
      entrance()
```

Comment: thanks that really helped, i'm somewhat new to python so i didn't really understand what i did wrong